# Perform function on pairs of rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(data=['A','B','C','D','E'], columns=['Name'])
>>> df
  Name
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
>>>
```

I want to create a list of values for adjacent rows in the dataframe. If I create an index of pairs I can get that result by using groupby:

```
>>> df.index=[0,0,1,1,2]
>>> df.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: list(x))
     Name
0  [A, B]
1  [C, D]
2     [E]
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The most efficient way to "I want to create a list of values for adjacent rows in the dataframe." is don't. Keep it as the df and do whatever it is you need to do. See also [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/184179).

Comment: So is the issue that I'm creating lists in my dataframe or that I'm applying a function to adjacent rows? I just used the list function arbitrarily in this example and am more interested generally in how to apply a function to adjacent rows.

Comment: You can write your own function that accepts a subdataframe in the groupby... what function do you want to apply? Or is the question how to groupby adjacency?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The question is indeed how to groupby adjacency. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can groupby by "adjacency" in one go (without mutating the DataFrame):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby(df.index // 2)
```

and then do whatever it is you need to do:

```
In [12]: g.get_group(0)
Out[12]:
  Name
0    A
1    B

In [13]: g.sum()
Out[13]:
  Name
0   AB
1   CD
2    E
```